# Prove 2^(n a) = O(2^n)?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

How can I prove that 2^(n+a) is O(2^n)? The only thing I can think of is that n in 2^n is an arbitrary value, therefore n+a is just as arbitrary, so n+a = n. Alternatively, 2^(n+a) = 2^n * 2^a. 2^n is obviously O(2^n), and a exists as an arbitrary value in 2^a, so 2^a = 2^n =  O(2^n). Is there a clearer/more formal way to prove this?

Comment: What is `a`? Is it a constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the formal definition of big-O, there must exist an M and n0 such that 2^(n+a) <= M*2^n for all n > n0.

If we choose M = 2^a, and n0 = 0, then we can see that 2^(n+a) = 2^a * 2^n = M*2^n, which is <= M*2^n for all n > n0. Therefore, 2^(n+a) is O(2^n)

Answer (score 1):

See the definition of the big-O notation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition). Think about whether you can find a constant `M` as in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to prove that `f(n)` is `O(g(n))`, you must find a positive integer `N` such that for all `n >= N`, `f(n) <= g(n)`.